# how to get cell range values with background colors in to single array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to write the script as shown below. It is necessary to combine the values and background colors in this cell range into a single array. But it does not come as needed.
[image: cell range]

```
    function newsheet(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AddData");

 //get category if checked
  var catList = ss.getRange("I5:J31").getValues();
  var catClrs = ss.getRange("J5:J31").getBackgrounds();
  var c = catList.map((key,index) => ({[key]:catClrs[index]}));
  Logger.log(c);
}
```

The answer comes this way
[image: Log result]

But I want an outcome like this.

```
    [{Extra,true,#b6d7a8}, {Extra,false,#ffffff}, {Extra,false,#ffffff}, {Ldrain ,false,#ffffff}, {Dish Drain,true,#0c343d}, {U drain,true,#274e13}, {Hard Sholder,true,#00ffff}, {Soft Sholder,true,#cc0000}, {As. wearing,true,#ff9900}, {Tack coat Wearing,true,#fce5cd}, {As.Binder,true,#9900ff}, {Tack Coat binder,true,#46bdc6}, {Prime coat,true,#000000}, {ABC overlay,false,#ffffff}, {Subbase overlay,true,#980000}, {Edgewidning ABC,true,#999999}, {Edgewidning Subbase,false,#ffffff}, {SubGrade Ew,true,#0000ff}, {Embankment 5,true,#9fc5e8}, {Embankment 4,true,#6fa8dc}, {Embankment 3,true,#3d85c6}, {Embankment 2,true,#0b5394}, {Embankment 1,true,#1c4587}, {Subgrade Emb,true,#8e7cc3}, {Soft Ground tratment 1,true,#c27ba0}, {Soft Ground tratment 2,true,#a64d79}, {Clearing & grabbing,true,#f1c232}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get these two values 'catList' , 'catClrs' into the same array at the same time without taking them separately in the apps script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this because it will be easier to read the values as you iterate through the array by having property labels for the object

```
function myobject(){
      const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
      var sh = ss.getSheetByName("AddData");
      var catList = sh.getRange("I5:J31").getValues();
      var catClrs = sh.getRange("J5:J31").getBackgrounds().flat();
      let c=[];
      catList.forEach((row,i) => {c.push({label:row[0],value:row[1],color:catClrs[i]})});
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(c));
    }
```

With my fake data:

```
[{"label":3,"value":21,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":0,"value":17,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":5,"value":29,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":29,"value":25,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":16,"value":24,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":17,"value":15,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":22,"value":4,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":6,"value":1,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":4,"value":28,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":14,"value":28,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":13,"value":1,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":2,"value":15,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":23,"value":6,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":14,"value":24,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":21,"value":6,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":12,"value":18,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":12,"value":7,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":5,"value":5,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":2,"value":0,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":16,"value":16,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":15,"value":21,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":0,"value":25,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":20,"value":6,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":24,"value":23,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":22,"value":0,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":14,"value":15,"color":"#ffffff"},{"label":24,"value":6,"color":"#ffffff"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Added `flat()`
2. Replaced `key` by `row`, `index` by `i` and `({[key]:catClrs[index]})` by `[row[0],row[1],catClrs[i]]`

```
function newsheet(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AddData");

 //get category if checked
  var catList = ss.getRange("I5:J31").getValues();
  var catClrs = ss.getRange("J5:J31").getBackgrounds().flat();
  var c = catList.map((row,i) => [row[0],row[1],catClrs[i]]);
  Logger.log(c);
}
```

The result will be slightly different because `{}` is used for objects and objects requires a key and a value.

---

I changed `key` by row to make the variable name closer to what it's holding as usually a "key" is a string but in this case it's an Array holding the values of two cells in the same row. `i` is shorter than `index`.

Comment: not working correctly in apps script google sheet

Comment: @TipVisor I'm sorry. I updated my answer.

Comment: why are you replace ( 'key') and ('index') ? Because of the entanglement?

Comment: @TipVisor I changed `key` by row to make the variable name closer to what it's holding as usually a "key" is a string but in this case it's an Array holding the values of two cells in the same row. `i` is shorter than `index` :)

Comment: That's great. thank you. Asking this for awareness. How to make the background gray in the code sections when commenting?

Comment: Are you using the old editor or the new one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228910/discussion-between-tipvisor-and-ruben).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing new compared to the accepted answer, but just shortening your code and a slighty better performance:

```
function newsheet(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("AddData");
  const range = ss.getRange("I5:J31");
  const [catList,catClrs] = [range.getValues(),range.getBackgrounds()];
  const c = catList.map((row,i) => [row[0],row[1],catClrs[0][i]]);
  Logger.log(c);
}
```

If you want to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the `true` values:

```
function newsheet(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("AddData");
  const range = ss.getRange("I5:J31");
  const [catList,catClrs] = [range.getValues(),range.getBackgrounds()];
  const c = catList.map((row,i) => [row[0],row[1],catClrs[0][i]]).filter(r=>r[1]);
  Logger.log(c);
}
```

Comment: thank you @Marios.  At this point you can filter only the True values (Checked) ​​and put them in "c".

Comment: @TipVisor is that a question or suggestion? Let me know if you need to get the `true` values only and I will modify the answer.

Comment: @TipVisor I actually modified my answer. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: your answer not working correctly.  Filtering did not work. "checked" they were filtered but did not get the corresponding background colors.
In addition, in the array you received in your method, only the first "unchecked box" received the values of the background colors. I'll put the methodology that works best for me.

Comment: @TipVisor sorry I made a mistake. Try again please.

Comment: I tried. But was not correct. The backgroungd color value is "null" after the first "false". Ex. [[Extra, true, #ffffff], [U drain, true, null], ....

Comment: @TipVisor don't know why . It worked for me. Maybe you have different dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked correctly. In addition to what is mentioned in the question, the method of filtering is also included.

```
function newsheet(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AddData");
  
//get category
  var catList = ss.getRange("I5:J31").getValues();
  var catClrs = ss.getRange("J5:J31").getBackgrounds().flat();
//merge arrays
  var c = catList.map((row,i) => [row[0],row[1],catClrs[i]]);
//filter "checked" boxes values
var fillterC = c.filter(filterLogic);    
}    

//create filter logic function
var filterLogic =function(item){
  if(item[1] === true){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped. I learned a lot.

Comment: two modifications (see my answer), `item[1]` is by default boolean, so you don't need `===`. You can replace `if(item[1] === true)` by `if(item[1])`. Also check my answer which uses arrow functions so you can write the same code in fewer lines of code.